# How to disable mtp connection from android devices

Tags: linux, usb, mtp

I tried all possibilities of blocking USB storage and it also worked for pen drives, external HDD but not the storage of mobile.
Can I block all of the mobile storage access?

OS is `Linux mint`.

Comment: Not sure this can be done easily, see : https://askubuntu.com/questions/868098/disable-automount-of-a-specific-mtp-device
Isn't it simpler to put your Android device on "charge only" ?

Answer (score 2):

At last I found the solution for it  for disabling access of any MTP connection and any i phone storage access.
u just need to disable the or remove the permission by root access.
in a clear word u have to remove the program which helps to mounts the access of phones.
you have to just do is open file system in linux mint and then open usr folder as root and then open lib folder in it and then find gvfs folder and search for and just click right click on gvfsd-mtp and select permission and remove the tick mark to allow the program to run. 
And then for i phone you can remove the same permission by selecting gvfsd-afc and then try connecting any android devices or iphone and you are done the phones would just charge instead of mounting the storage.

Comment: it surely works try it

Comment: Such a simple solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You can remove the access by using this command as superuser in terminal.

```
apt-get remove usbmuxd
```

but this should be done at your own risk because it removes other supporting files including GUI supporting files.

Comment: ["(*usbmuxd is a*) Usb multiplexor daemon for iphone and ipod touch devices"](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/usbmuxd), so how would that affect Android devices (mentioned in the title of the Q)?